# XPATH/Python/Scrapy - How to append text to href

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy with Python to scrape a page.  My goals are to:

1.Get the **href** value from the **a** tag and append **https:/careers.infinity.aero/** before the href value
2.Export this list to a `csv` file
3.Run a 2nd script to pull those URLs for another scrape

I'm stuck at trying to get the concat to work for XPATH - I believe it's a disconnect for the syntax or the placement for the **href**, but I've not had much luck finding anything to help me.

Here is what I've got:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class dgtest2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dgtest2"
    start_urls = [
    'https://careers.infinity.aero/Careers.aspx'
    ]

    custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'urls.csv'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('concat( string("https://careers.infinity.aero/"), //a/@href)').getall()
        yield {
            'URL': url,
        }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(dgtest2)
process.start()
```

I've had success with importing from `csv` file in my 2nd script, I've had success with pulling the **href** using:

```
url = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
```

and exporting it to a `csv` file, but the **href** values are only a partial URL, which is why I need to append.

Any info would be appreciate.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate two parts of a url into one, you can either use the standard library `urljoin` function or you can use the `scrapy` provided convinience method `response.urljoin`.

USING RESPONSE OBJECT

```
def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath("//a/@href").getall():
            yield {
            'URL': response.urljoin(url),
            }
```

USING STANDARD LIBRARY (take note of the import)

```
def parse(self, response):
        from urllib.parse import urljoin
        for url in response.xpath("//a/@href").getall():
            yield {
            'URL': urljoin("https:/careers.infinity.aero/", url),
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The 2nd option worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if this was helpful